# Telegraf boot-up issue

Tags: mosquitto, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

I tried to setup the tool chain of mosquitto, telegraf, and influxdb. All three are installed
on a raspberry pi using apt. To debug, I use a file output from telegraf.

This connection does not work when the pi boots. Mosquito is working if subscribed from outside.
telegraf collects system and disk information. However telegraf does not collect mqtt information.

When I restart mosquitto like

```
sudo service mosquitto stop
mosquitto -v
```

the connection is working.

When I restart mosquitto like

```
sudo service mosquitto stop
sudo service mosquitto start
```

it is again not working.

What could be the difference?

I just upgraded to the latest versions, but that did not change anything.

- mosquitto 1.5.7
- telegraf 1.15.3
- influxdb 1.8.2

The boot messages of mosquitto are fine:

```
Sep 14 21:34:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Mosquitto MQTT v3.1/v3.1.1 Broker... 
Sep 14 21:34:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Mosquitto MQTT v3.1/v3.1.1 Broker.
```

The boot messages from telegraf report connection to mosquitto, though there is some trouble with influxdb

```
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi telegraf[401]: 2020-09-14T19:34:54Z I! Starting Telegraf 1.15.3
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi influxd[407]: ts=2020-09-14T19:34:54.300652Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0PFXdCuW000 service=store trace_id=0PFXdEbG000 op_name=tsdb_open index_version=inmem path=/var/lib/influxdb/data/base/autogen/16 duration=598.507ms
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi influxd[407]: ts=2020-09-14T19:34:54.300796Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0PFXdCuW000 service=store trace_id=0PFXdEbG000 op_name=tsdb_open index_version=inmem path=/var/lib/influxdb/data/base/autogen/152 duration=675.711ms
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi influxd[407]: ts=2020-09-14T19:34:54.366628Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0PFXdCuW000 engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/data/base/autogen/2/000000001-000000001.tsm id=0 duration=11.324ms
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi influxd[407]: ts=2020-09-14T19:34:54.374469Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0PFXdCuW000 engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/data/base/autogen/24/000000319-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=22.091ms
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi telegraf[401]: 2020-09-14T19:34:54Z I! Loaded inputs: system mqtt_consumer disk
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi telegraf[401]: 2020-09-14T19:34:54Z I! Loaded aggregators:
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi telegraf[401]: 2020-09-14T19:34:54Z I! Loaded processors:
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi telegraf[401]: 2020-09-14T19:34:54Z I! Loaded outputs: influxdb file
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi telegraf[401]: 2020-09-14T19:34:54Z I! Tags enabled: host=raspberrypi
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi telegraf[401]: 2020-09-14T19:34:54Z I! [agent] Config: Interval:10s, Quiet:false, Hostname:"raspberrypi", Flush Interval:10s
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi influxd[407]: ts=2020-09-14T19:34:54.489708Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0PFXdCuW000 service=store trace_id=0PFXdEbG000 op_name=tsdb_open index_version=inmem path=/var/lib/influxdb/data/base/autogen/2 duration=188.821ms
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi telegraf[401]: 2020-09-14T19:34:54Z I! [inputs.mqtt_consumer] Connected [tcp://localhost:1883]
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi influxd[407]: ts=2020-09-14T19:34:54.548591Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0PFXdCuW000 service=store trace_id=0PFXdEbG000 op_name=tsdb_open index_version=inmem path=/var/lib/influxdb/data/base/autogen/24 duration=239.663ms
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi influxd[407]: ts=2020-09-14T19:34:54.552787Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0PFXdCuW000 engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/data/base/autogen/32/000000271-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=22.821ms
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi influxd[407]: ts=2020-09-14T19:34:54.788229Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0PFXdCuW000 engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/data/base/autogen/62/000000006-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=203.005ms
Sep 14 21:34:54 raspberrypi influxd[407]: ts=2020-09-14T19:34:54.842928Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0PFXdCuW000 service=store trace_id=0PFXdEbG000 op_name=tsdb_open index_version=inmem path=/var/lib/influxdb/data/base/autogen/32 duration=352.965ms
Sep 14 21:34:56 raspberrypi influxd[407]: ts=2020-09-14T19:34:56.503706Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0PFXdCuW000 engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/data/base/autogen/40/000000004-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=71.762ms
Sep 14 21:34:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Succeeded.
Sep 14 21:34:59 raspberrypi influxd[407]: ts=2020-09-14T19:34:59.734290Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0PFXdCuW000 service=store trace_id=0PFXdEbG000 op_name=tsdb_open index_version=inmem path=/var/lib/influxdb/data/base/autogen/62 duration=5185.491ms
Sep 14 21:34:59 raspberrypi influxd[407]: ts=2020-09-14T19:34:59.762419Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0PFXdCuW000 engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/data/base/autogen/41/000000001-000000001.tsm id=0 duration=8.874ms
Sep 14 21:34:59 raspberrypi influxd[407]: ts=2020-09-14T19:34:59.785965Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0PFXdCuW000 service=store trace_id=0PFXdEbG000 op_name=tsdb_open index_version=inmem path=/var/lib/influxdb/data/base/autogen/40 duration=4942.818ms
```

The relevant parts oc telegraf.conf are

```
[[outputs.influxdb]]
  urls = ["http://127.0.0.1:8086"]
  database = "base"
  skip_database_creation = true
  username = "telegraf"
  password = "****"
  content_encoding = "identity"

[[outputs.file]]
 files = ["stdout", "/tmp/metrics.out"]

[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
servers = ["tcp://localhost:1883"]
topics = ["home/garden/+"]
topic_tag = "mqtt_topic"
qos = 1
max_undelivered_messages = 1
persistent_session = true
client_id = "lord_of_the_pis"

    data_format = "json"
```

Answer (score 0):

The client_id was the problem.

```
client_id = "lord_of_the_pis"
```

With a shorter client_id, it works fine.